# Equivalent type for CStringList

Tags: c++-cli, cstring

What should be the equivalent type:

```
CStringList
```

in C++/CLI?

I tried to use:

```
System::Collections::Generic::List<System::String ^>
```

but I am unable to convert it to CStringList for passing to the function being wrapped and vice versa. The function to be wrapped is:

```
void getEqui(CStringList& list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<String^>^` is the logical equivilent to CStringList, as you noted. However, there is no direct conversion, you'll need to iterate over the List, create CStrings, and insert them into the CStringList.